# numpy test if each value in row in row of another array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two arrays of the same shape (2500, 9). I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to test if each value in a row in `array1` is in the corresponding row in `array2`. Consider the following simplified example:

```
>>> array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 8, 9]])
>>> array2 = np.array([[0, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6], [6, 8, 9]])
>>> comparison_func(array1, array2)
array([False, True, False], 
      [False, True, True], 
      [False, True, True])
```

I can accomplish this by iterating over each value in `array1` and test if that value is in the corresponding row in `array2`.

```
>>> comp = []
>>> rows, columns = array1.shape
>>> np.array([array1[row, column] in array2[row, :]
              for row in range(rows)
              for column in range(columns)])
      .reshape(array1.shape)
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True]])
```

I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to do this in numpy. I tried various combinations of `np.isin` and `np.isin1d`, but could not limit the comparison to a scalar from `array1` to the corresponding row in `array2`. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter when you say `if each value in a row in array1 is in the corresponding row in array2`? For example, would `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 1, 2]` count as the same row in this case?

Comment: I am not comparing rows. I am determining if each scalar in a row is in the same row of another array of the same shape. The order does matter in that I need the booleans to have the same order as the values in array1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting and adding the new axis to properly compare each element of `array1` with all elements of corresponding row in `array2` (I assume you do not care about the position of your element in that row):

```
(array1[...,None]==array2[:,None,:]).any(-1)
```

output:

```
[[False  True False]
 [False  True  True]
 [False  True  True]]
```

---

**Comparison**:

```
#@U11-Forward's solution
def m1(array1, array2):
  return [[array2[i][x] == y for x, y in enumerate(v)] for i, v in enumerate(array1)]

#@Ehsan's solution
def m2(array1, array2):
  return (array1[...,None]==array2[:,None,:]).any(-1)


in_ = {n:[np.random.randint(10,size=(n,100)), np.random.randint(10,size=(n,100))] for n in [10,100,1000,10000]}
```

output:

[image]

**m2** seems to be faster for this input.

---

**Explanation**:
`None` in indexing is an alias for `np.newaxis`. Where ever you insert `None`, Numpy creates an extra dimension in that position (a.k.a. new axis). `array1[...,None]` is the same as `array1[:,:,None]`.

Now, the comparison `array1[...,None]==array2[:,None,:]` uses broadcasting of numpy to compare each element of `array1` with each element of `array2` in the same row. The output has an extra dimension. To check if each element of `array1` is in corresponding row of `array2`, it is enough to see if it is equal to `any` elements of `array2` in that row, hence `any(-1)`. `-1`  in python refers to the last index (here the last axis which corresponds to `array2`'s columns of the same row.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain how the broadcasting and any call works in this case? It looks like a possible solution but I am having trouble following the underlying logic.

Comment: @EricTruett Added explanation to the post. Hope it helps clarifying it. The best idea is to read numpy doc for better understanding and examples of broadcasting. (Adding axis/dimension is a pretty trivial concept)

Answer (score 2):

Numpy's `==` equal does it:

```
>>> array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 8, 9]])
>>> array2 = np.array([[0, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6], [6, 8, 9]])
>>> print(array1 == array2)
[[False  True False]
 [False  True  True]
 [False  True  True]]
>>>
```

The way Numpy does it is that they change the `__eq__` function to something else, that does the above.

Here is an example that how you would be able to make that happen in a python class:

```
class array:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.final = [[other[i][x] == y for x, y in enumerate(v)] for i, v in enumerate(self.lst)]
        return self.final
print(array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 8, 9]]) == [[0, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6], [6, 8, 9]])
```

Output:

```
[[False, True, False], [False, True, True], [False, True, True]]
```

Comment: This allows for element-by-element comparison, but produces the wrong answer if, for example, you flip the order of 2 and 3 in the first row of array1.